# Table Environment with Surrounding Spaces like Normal Paragraph

Tags: tables, spacing

Around a `tabular` environment, LaTeX produces different vertical spaces than a normal paragraph.
There are some answers here in LaTeX Stack Exchange that advise setting `\intextsep`, but I see no difference with it.

Is there a `tabular` environment which is positioned exactly like a normal text paragraph?

In my specific case, I am customising the nice [Deedy CV template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/deedy-resume-cv) with a table inside of a `minipage`, which in that template divides the layout into two columns:

```
some text

\sectionspace % Some whitespace after the section

%------------------------------------------------
% New section
%------------------------------------------------

\section{New section}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
aaa & bbb \\
\end{tabular}

\sectionspace % Some whitespace after the section

\begin{multicols}{2}
```

`\sectionspace` is simply `\vspace{8pt}`, as defined in the template style.
Notice that after the table there is `multicols`, which further splits the following text into two other columns.
However, the space is different than usual both before and after the table.

Comment: a tabular has no special spacing at all it is positioned just as a letter `X` is positioned. Can you make a small example document that shows the problem you see?

Comment: Of course, @DavidCarlisle, and thank you for answering me. I am referring to this nice CV template: https://github.com/deedydas/Deedy-Resume I will edit the question with further details

Comment: please fix the example so it is a complete document so that people can see what you see, and test answers. If possible use a standard class such as article, if the problem occurs there.

Answer (score 2):

You can test the vertical spacing by placing constructions side by side in a minipage, here you see that the tabular has the same spacing as a normal line of text and the following line in each of the minipages is at the same vertical position:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
aaa&bbb
\end{tabular}

aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa 
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa 

aaa bbb

aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```